# PhantomJS + Take Screenshot from app.powerbi.com gives a blank/white image

Tags: javascript, ubuntu-16.04, webpage-screenshot

I have PhantomJS working on test websites (tried google, youtube etc) and it gives me a screenshot. When trying to take screenshot from powerbi.com it gives me a blank page.

I am using the code from the rasterize.js example from PhantomJS

```
"use strict";
var page = require('webpage').create(),
    system = require('system'),
    address, output, size, pageWidth, pageHeight;

if (system.args.length < 3 || system.args.length > 5) {
    console.log('Usage: rasterize.js URL filename [paperwidth*paperheight|paperformat] [zoom]');
    console.log('  paper (pdf output) examples: "5in*7.5in", "10cm*20cm", "A4", "Letter"');
    console.log('  image (png/jpg output) examples: "1920px" entire page, window width 1920px');
    console.log('                                   "800px*600px" window, clipped to 800x600');
    phantom.exit(1);
} else {
    address = system.args[1];
    output = system.args[2];
    page.viewportSize = { width: 600, height: 600 };
    if (system.args.length > 3 && system.args[2].substr(-4) === ".pdf") {
        size = system.args[3].split('*');
        page.paperSize = size.length === 2 ? { width: size[0], height: size[1], margin: '0px' }
                                           : { format: system.args[3], orientation: 'portrait', margin: '1cm' };
    } else if (system.args.length > 3 && system.args[3].substr(-2) === "px") {
        size = system.args[3].split('*');
        if (size.length === 2) {
            var pageWidth = parseInt(size[0], 10),
                pageHeight = parseInt(size[1], 10);
            page.viewportSize = { width: pageWidth, height: pageHeight };
            page.clipRect = { top: 0, left: 0, width: pageWidth, height: pageHeight };
        } else {
            console.log("size:", system.args[3]);
            var pageWidth = parseInt(system.args[3], 10),
                pageHeight = parseInt(pageWidth * 3/4, 10); // it's as good an assumption as any
            console.log ("pageHeight:",pageHeight);
            page.viewportSize = { width: pageWidth, height: pageHeight };
        }
    }
    if (system.args.length > 4) {
        page.zoomFactor = system.args[4];
    }
    page.open(address, function (status) {
        if (status !== 'success') {
            console.log('Unable to load the address!');
            phantom.exit(1);
        } else {
            window.setTimeout(function () {
                page.render(output);
                phantom.exit();
            }, 200);
        }
    });
}
```

I the use the command line to generate a picture:

```
phantomjs --ssl-protocol=tlsv1 --ignore-ssl-errors=yes --debug=true rasterize.js https://app.powerbi.com/view?r=eyJrIjoiOTBhODY4ODUtMWU3Ny00NGRjLTlhYjItMWM3ZjUyMzA5ZjY1IiwidCI6IjU3NGMzZTU2LTQ5MjQtNDAwNC1hZDFhLWQ4NDI3ZTdkYjI0MSIsImMiOjZ9 /var/www/html/screenshot/test.png
```

This results in a blank/white generated image. Not sure if the site or program is compatible?

Answer (score 0):

Updated to prebuilt (version 2.1.1) and it now works.

Comment: It will be great if you could look through the code and help us understand whats missing https://pastebin.com/jLCZ3Crn

Comment: Got the same issue. Phantomjs is not loading powerbi embedded reports. Showing blank. Can someone help me here, i am stuck?